# Runtime error 1004 with Count and Countif formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting run time error 1004 when converting the following formula to code:

When I try to consider the only Count forumlas, it was working.

Formula:

```
=(COUNT(C25:C26)-COUNTIF(C25:C26,0))/(COUNT(E25:E26)-COUNTIF(E25:E26,0))
```

Code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(29, 3).Formula = "=(COUNT(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(25, 3), Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) _
& "- COUNTIF(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(25, 3), Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0 )/" & _
"(COUNT(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(25, 5), Cells(26, 5)).Address(False, False) _
& "- COUNTIF(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(25, 5), Cells(26, 5)).Address(False, False) & ",0 ))"
```

Comment: Fully qualify `Cells(25, 3)` to `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(25, 3)`. Similarly for others

Comment: You may also want to declare `Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws =ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` So that you could write `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(29, 3)` as `ws.Cells(29, 3)`. Similarly you can replace all `Sheets("Sheet1")` with `ws`. Less of typing and easier to manage ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout may I asked what do you mean by fully qualify the cells?

Comment: `Cells(25, 3)` if not qualified will refer to the active sheet which may not be Sheet1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **forgot some brakets/parenthesis and let spaces**.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(29, 3).Formula = _
    "=(COUNT(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) _
    & ")-COUNTIF(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0))/" & _
    "(COUNT(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) _
    & ")-COUNTIF(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0))"
End With
```

Use a string variable to debug and prompt it with a `MsgBox`.

```
Dim StrFormula As String
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    StrFormula = _
    "=(COUNT(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) _
    & ")-COUNTIF(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0))/" & _
    "(COUNT(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) _
    & ")-COUNTIF(" & .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0))"
End With
MsgBox StrFormula
```

Comment: If you fully qualify your cells object then this would be what OP wants :)

Comment: Now it makes more sense ;)

Comment: I always hesitated with `Range`, if I need to qualify `Cells` inside to or not, but now I'll remember! Thx mate! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it to confusing,

```
Range("C29") = _
"=(COUNT(Sheet1!R[-4]C:R[-3]C)-COUNTIF(Sheet1!R[-4]C:R[-3]C,0))/(COUNT(Sheet1!R[-4]C[2]:R[-3]C[2])-COUNTIF(Sheet1!R[-27]C[2]:R[-4]C[2],0))"
'or
Range("C29") = _
"=(COUNT(Sheet1!C25:C26)-COUNTIF(Sheet1!C25:C26,0))/(COUNT(Sheet1!E25:E26)-COUNTIF(Sheet1!E2:E25,0))"
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comments, this is how you will qualify your cells object. Notice the DOT before cells?

**Tested**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sFormula As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        sFormula = "=(COUNT(" & _
                    .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ")" & _
                    "- COUNTIF(" & _
                    .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0 ))/" & _
                    "(COUNT(" & _
                    .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ")" & _
                    "- COUNTIF(" & _
                    .Range(.Cells(25, 3), .Cells(26, 3)).Address(False, False) & ",0 ))"

        Debug.Print sFormula

        .Cells(29, 3).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You miss spaces and brackets as corrected in my answer ;)

Comment: @R3uK: Correct. :) The code was untested. Now it is rested. Thanks